# How to change the background color of a combobox in ms access using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

So I have a ms access form with a bunch of a comboboxes in it. I want to change the background of the combobox to red if it's null and its past the end date of the project. I have attached my code snippet below. so far it's only changing the background color of the list, not the combobox itself. the code snippet is set to run during the form open event.

```
If Me.Combo1.Visible = True Then

    If IsNull(Me.Combo1) = False Then

        textsum = textsum + 1
        totalcount = totalcount + 1

    Else

        totalcount = totalcount + 1

        If Me.ProjectEndDate<= Date Then

            Me.Combo1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

        End If

    End If
End if
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. I've copied it to a blank database, created a form with a textbox (ProjectEndDate) and a Combo1. I've tried all possible combinations (enddate null, >date, <date, combo empty or pre-filled). The combo shows up with a red background when expected. So my guess is, there is something else.

Comment: Have you tried using this code in Form_current and combine it with a `Painting`?